# Java: How to configure System.out to have autoflush enabled?

Tags: java, flush, printwriter, system.out, autoflush

I used reflection like so to print out the properties of the `System.out` object:

```
System.out.println("Class: " + System.out.getClass().getName());
for (Field field : ObjectUtils.getAllFields(System.out)) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("> " + field.getType().getSimpleName() + ' ' + field.getName() + " = " + field.get(System.out));
}
```

This was the result:

```
Class: java.io.PrintStream
> boolean autoFlush = false
> boolean trouble = false
> Formatter formatter = null
> BufferedWriter textOut = java.io.BufferedWriter@43c1b556
> OutputStreamWriter charOut = java.io.OutputStreamWriter@587e5365
> boolean closing = false
> OutputStream out = org.apache.tools.ant.util.TeeOutputStream@22fcf7ab
```

As you can see, the `autoflush` is set to `false`.  So my question is simple -- how do I configure `System.out` to have `autoflush` set to `true`?

Comment: What jvm are you using? I receive autoFlush = true, which is consistent with OpenJDK source code, both for Java 8 and Java 11. For Java11 check: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L1968 and https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L1886

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in another stream:

```java
PrintStream newOut = new PrintStream(System.out, true);
// And then set it to out (Credit to David Zimmerman in the comments)
System.setOut(newOut);
```

Comment: Then System.setOut(newOut)

Comment: For more details check the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,boolean)

Comment: Or a one-liner: `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true));`

Answer (score -1):

After [`System.out.println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) execute [`System.out.flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush())

Comment: Not really what **auto**-flush means though.